# How to delete records in asp.net using ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ajax, sql-delete

I am listing a page with content from database. I would like to add delete functionality to it. I am using asp placeholder to place the data on page. Also I am using Phone number as Primary Key.I tried searching for it. But nothing worked for me. Also it will be great if we can use delete using ajax.

This is for a test recipes page using asp.net using C# and SQL Server.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {
                //Populating a DataTable from database.
                DataTable dt = this.GetData();

                //Building an HTML string.
                StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();

                //div structure
                html.Append("<div class='container contest-wrapper'>");
                //dynamic divs
                int row_count = dt.Rows.Count;
                html.Append("<div class='col-md-12'>");
                html.Append("<p>Total Entries:" + row_count + "</p>");
                html.Append("</div>");
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {

                    html.Append("<div class='col-md-6 main-container'>");
                    html.Append("<div class='single-contest'>");
                    html.Append("<div class='collapse methodDiv' id='" + row["PhNo"].ToString() + "'><p>" + row["DishMethod"].ToString() + "</p></div>");
                    html.Append("<img class='img-responsive contest-img' src='" + row["DishImg"].ToString() + "'>");
                    //html.Append("<a runat='server' id='" + row["PhNo"].ToString()+ "' onserverclick='Delete(" + row["PhNo"].ToString() + ")' >Delete</a>");
                    //html.Append("<input type='hidden' runat='server' name='hdnPhNo' value='" + row["PhNo"].ToString() + "' />");
                    //html.Append("<input runat='server' OnClick='Delete(" + row["PhNo"].ToString() + ")' type='submit' name='buttonDelete' value='Delete Entry' />");
                    //html.Append("<button ID='delete' runat='server' Text='Delete' OnClick='delete(" + row["PhNo"].ToString() + ")'>Delete</button>");
                    html.Append("<p><b>Dish Name: </b>");
                    html.Append(row["DishName"].ToString());
                    html.Append("</p>");
                    html.Append("<p><b>Uploaded By: </b>");
                    html.Append(row["UserName"].ToString());
                    html.Append("</p>");
                    html.Append("<p><b>Email: </b>");
                    html.Append(row["Email"].ToString());
                    html.Append("</p>");
                    html.Append("<p><b>Phone Number: </b>");
                    html.Append(row["PhNo"].ToString());
                    html.Append("</p>");
                    //html.Append("<p><b>Dish Method: </b>");
                    //html.Append(row["DishMethod"].ToString());
                    //html.Append("</p>");
                    html.Append("<button type='button' class='method-btn' data-toggle='collapse'  onclick='setColor(event)'; data-count='1'  data-target='#"+ row["PhNo"].ToString() + "'>Method</button>");
                    html.Append("</div>");
                    html.Append("</div>");
                }
                //dynamic divs
                html.Append("</div>");
                //div structure

                //Append the HTML string to Placeholder.
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = html.ToString() });
            }
        }
        private DataTable GetData()
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RecipeDataModel"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM RecipeContest"))
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                        {
                            sda.Fill(dt);
                            return dt;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public void delete(object sender, EventArgs e, int phNo)
        {
            //string phNo = hdnPhNo.Value;
            //string phNo = Request["hdnPhNo"];
            string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RecipeDataModel"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = null;
            conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
            conn.Open(); SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM RecipeContest WHERE PhNo='" + phNo + "'";
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            int numberDeleted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //Display success message.
            string message = "Your details have been deleted successfully.";
            string script = "window.onload = function(){ alert('";
            script += message;
            script += "')};";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "SuccessMessage", script, true);
        }
```

I would like to get one record to be deleted after click on its corresponding delete button. If AJax can be implemented that would be great as well.

Comment: You build your HTML using a `StringBuilder`.... o_O

Comment: **Please** research how to use [Stored Procedures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-2017) or parameter queries, as your code is currently open to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: When deleting, why would you delete by Phone Number? I'm aware it could be unique, but what if it's not provided? Delete by ID or unique key instead. Also, beware of SQL Injection with your current approach.

Comment: you gonna need a webservice or implement Webmethods in your codebehind (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.services.webmethodattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2 or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-web-services). Calling it by Javascript, wait for the succes and then removing it from the site by Javascript

Comment: Instead of creating HTML Content at runtime, you might want to use repeater control with ItemTemplate.  Then you can use ItemCommand event repeater and delete the item from it. Also you can do AJAX to delete the item from it easily.

Answer (score 0):

Prone to SQL injection

```
cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM RecipeContest WHERE PhNo='" + phNo + "'";
```

always use parameter example would be

```
cmd.CommandText =”Delete From RecipeContest where PhNo=@phno” 
cmd.Parameter.AddWithValue(“@phno”,phno);
```

or you can do it like this too for the above line
    cmd.Parameters["@phno"].Value = phNo;
the rest looks fine with me if you want to delete by telephone numbers , I do suggest using the record ID.
Here is the link for sql delete 
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp